# Chrome stopped autofilling email and password fields after changing keyring permissions

Tags: google-chrome, password, keyrings

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and I changed the keyring permissions so I would not have to enter my password in each time I opened Chrome. Now Chrome does not autofill the email and password fields. In settings, there are no saved passwords, but in the password manager, they are all there.

I have already synced my account. Is there a way to change the keyring back to default? I would rather have to enter a password once than my password on every site.

Answer (score 4):

I believe, this will help. I don't think the problem is directly related to the keyring. Try resetting your Chrome configuration. Open a terminal and delete the old config.

```
rm -r ~/.config/google-chrome
```

Then when you open chrome you will need to renter your google password and it will re-sync.

Or, if you prefer to have a backup of your old configuration, it would be something like

```
mv ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.config/google-chrome.bak
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked!

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to delete all the data that is stored in chrome directory you can delete only `Login Data` and `Login Data-journal` also any other file that has similar naming.

```
cd ~/.config/google-chrome
```

If you have multiple profiles you will see directories like `Default` `Profile 1` `Profile 2` you will need to perform same action for all of those. You need to enter each of these directories and run:

```
rm 'Login Data' 'Login Data-journal'
```